# Control geometry types of new objects in a PostGIS Geometry type column

Tags: qgis

In a PostGIS table with a geometry column of type 'Geometry' containing MultiLineStrings and MultiPolygons QGIS wants to load these as MultiCurve and MultiSurface layers. When I create a new object on one of these layers it is of type MultiCurve or MultiSurface. However I would like MultiLineStrings and MultiPolygons for compatibility with other processes e.g. filtering objects by geometry type.

I can not change the Spatial Type in the Data Source Manager. I'm running 3.28.1. What can I do to force creation of MultiLineStrings and MultiPolygons instead of MultiCurves and MultiSurfaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem : I used a trigger to convert multisurfaces into multipolygons when I create features. For the function :

```
CREATE FUNCTION myConvert() returns trigger as
&&
BEGIN
 IF st_geometrytype(NEW.geom) like '%surface%' THEN NEW.geom = st_multi(st_curvetoLine(NEW.geom))
 END IF;
END;
&&;
```

Then create the trigger.

Comment: Nice function. I was using st_curvetoline() manually. I was hoping to do it in QGIS but this at least makes it a lot easier to do in PostGIS. Thanks.